# Xposed for Galaxy J2

Tags: installation, xposed-framework

Recently I switched my phones to better one of Samsung, named as Samsung Galaxy J2 (2016 edition) with TouchWiz ROM..

I rooted it and had some apps installed, but when I got the Xposed Framework, unlike my previous phone, it gave a **warning** before the installation (attached pic) that kept me away to install it

[[image: Xposed gives TouchWiz ROM warning[1]]

So ultimately my question is, will it brick my device?

(J2's stock rom isn't available yet, so I'm trying to prevent any issues)..

If yes, is there any alternative way to fix this issue and install the framework?

Any comments would be highly appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: You need to use [Wanam's Xposed](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3180960), not the regular one

Comment: @GokulNC The Xposed Installer app was able to correctly download the appropriate framework for a Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo, in my experience.

Comment: @DeathMask Yeah, I think what you're talking about is the unofficial Xposed Installer by dvdandroid; that's not supported by the official one I guess.. We don't know if the OP uses the official or unofficial one..

Comment: Since you already voided your warranty, you might want to find a custom recovery for your phone, which allows you to do a Nandroid backup, a form of backup that saves your phone's current state. This way, should Xposed mess up your system, you'll be able to revert to a working state.

Comment: For custom rec., i got TWRP and i rooted by flashing a zip of supersu

Comment: @GokulNC Indeed, and that's why I suggested to make a Nandroid backup first and foremost.

Comment: With a custom recovery, you could just _flash_ Wanam's Xposed instead of trying to install it from the installer. Do remember to backup as others said.

Comment: I just did it and it worked too... but i still have a question. .. the thread asked me to install the Xposed framework app provided and so i did but what if i install the lastest framework available at original post?

Comment: If you mean the original (not Wanam's) version of Xposed... It sends you into a bootloop.